# What causes the "Not unique table/alias" error?

Tags: sql

Database Error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'funnel'

```
SQL Query: SELECT `funnel`.`id`
FROM `salescrm`.`funnel` AS `funnel`
LEFT JOIN `salescrm`.`funnel` AS `funnel` ON (`funnel`.`id` = `funnel`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `salescrm`.`users` AS `User` ON (`funnel`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `funnel`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
```

> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

Comment: The alias `funnel` is used twice and that causes the error. Do you need the `LEFT JOIN `  on `salescrm.funnel` ?

Comment: (The error message says what it means..)